# After creating array of objects how to update a key value of object? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I got something simple but I'm obviously too stupid.

I have two inputs in my HTML. 1st is company and 2nd is shares. I'm creating UL with the companies. The thing is I want to do that when I enter a company name that already exist in the array I want to update the shares of that company only. I will share the code I made so far.

```
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="company" placeholder="Company" type="text" />
      <input id="input" placeholder="Shares" type="number" />
      <button id="btn">Add</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="content"></ul>
  </body>
```

And the JavaScript code is here:

```
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const content = document.getElementById("content");

let companiesArray = [];

function myCompany(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputShares = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const inputCompany = document.getElementById("company").value;
  let obj = {
    company: inputCompany,
    shares: inputShares,
  };
  for (const item of companiesArray) {
    if (item.company === obj.company) {
      //TO DO
      console.log("Match");
      return;
    }
  }
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  content.appendChild(li).textContent = `${obj.company} - ${obj.shares}`;
  companiesArray = [...companiesArray, obj];
  console.log(companiesArray);
}

button.addEventListener("click", myCompany);
```

So again, when I enter a unique company => li is created in the ul. If I enter the same company I just want to update the shares without adding new li.

Comment: To replace the `textContent` of an `li`, just assign it the new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (item.company === obj.company) {
        //TO DO
        const list = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
        const element = [...list].filter((item) => item.innerText.split(" ")[0] === obj.company)[0]
        element.innerText = `${obj.company} - ${obj.shares}`
        console.log("Match");
        return;
      }
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: That works. Thank you! My bad, but the idea was when you add an existing company the shares to be added to the previous shares. For example you add Apple with 2 shares. Then you add again Apple but with 5 shares. Now Apple should be with 7 shares. I will try to do it by myself now but if any problems I'll give you a shout. :)

Comment: Sure. Happy to help :)